# Plesk – I have to migrate PHP 5 version to PHP 7 or greater to run the application and take time as we getting errors

Tags: laravel, putty, plesk

With Plesk – I have to migrate PHP 5 version to PHP 7 or greater  to run the application and it take time getting errors and have to make the changes in my web app code and fix all errors accordingly . After that have to install laravel on plesk and run application.  But as Plesk saying they officially not support the Laravel . so not 100% sure with this option .  As currently even I am not able to access server by SSH using  putty its server problem  not allowing me to access .

And one more thing my putty is not working it show timout issue all the time, even not able to see any content what am typing

Below are the screenshot of the errors

[plesk server dashboard for setting subdomain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heOrV.png)

[link opening error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wxO3.png)

Comment: I just see a problem description. What exactly would you like to know? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hire a professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the default `index.html`, because it is exactly what you are seeing in a web browser.

> Plesk saying they officially not support the Laravel

That is not really true. Indeed, Plesk is not shipped with Laravel, therefore, Plesk support representatives would not be resolving issues related to application code.

Laravel is not included in APS catalog also, so it is up to the domain owner to perform the installation and to troubleshoot if something goes wrong with the installation.

I strongly suggest referring to [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6) and [Plesk documentation](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/)/[Help Center](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us) for better understanding of task which should be performed for the installation and to avoid simple mistakes, and asking only descriptive and well-formed questions on Stack Overflow. Otherwise, they cannot be addressed in a proper way.

Or, if you don't feel like learning and just need this thing done, hire a professional as advised earlier.